# Copy row value to another row for every instance

Tags: sql-server, copy

My SQL Server table `Company_Month_Coupon` looks like this:

- ID
- CompanyID
- Month
- Total_Coupons
- Year

There was a mistake: all values from july have been set to august.

What I want do to is to select the value of august and copy it to July.

How can I do this for each company?

I tried this:

```
UPDATE Company_Month_Coupons
SET Total_Coupons = (SELECT Total_Coupons 
                     FROM Company_Month_Coupon 
                     WHERE Month = 8 AND Year = YEAR(GETDATE()))
WHERE Month = 7 AND Year = YEAR(GETDATE())
```

But this returns:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Answer (score 0):

You must have more than one record with Month = 8 and Year = 2018. Otherwise you would not be getting that error.

Comment: for each companyID, i indeed have a record

Comment: If you run SELECT Total_Coupons FROM Company_Month_Coupon WHERE Month = 8 AND Year = YEAR(GETDATE()) how many records do you get? If it's more than 1, then that's the problem.

Comment: This is really more comment than answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
UPDATE c

SET c.Total_Coupons = c1.Total_Coupons 

from Company_Month_Coupons c
join Company_Month_Coupons c1
on c.CompanyID = c1.CompanyID
and c.year = c1.year
and c.month = 8 and c1.month  = 7
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is the entire issue,

> There was a mistake: all values from july have been set to august.

then the solution seems pretty straight forward.

If there are empty records for July to contend with, then you may need to delete those first. If you have two sets of records, you'll eventually have to delete one or the other, no matter how you approach the problem.

```
DELETE
FROM Company_Month_Coupons 
WHERE 
  Month = 7
  AND
  Year = 2018;
```

Then change all of the August records into July records.

```
UPDATE Company_Month_Coupons 
  SET Month = 7
WHERE 
  Month = 8
  AND
  Year = 2018;
```